# Recursively look up PostgreSQL 10 hierarchy

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance, recursive-query

I've been toying with recursive queries and have most of the information I need, but in our schema, we have a setting that can be inherited to the child of a parent. When the child inherits the parent setting, it's own setting is set to NULL. This relationship can span multiple levels (example: 4th child inherits from a parent at the top.

We're using PostgreSQL 10.

An example table of this data looks like:

Customers (there's no actual 'inheritance' column in our schema... that is just to identify those)

| id | name | parent_id | customer_settings | inheritance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | parent customer A | 1 | 1234501 | not inherited |
| 3 | child of A sub 1 | 2 | null | inherited |
| 4 | child of A sub 2 | 2 | 1234502 | not inherited |
| 5 | child of A2 sub 1 | 4 | null | inherited |
| 6 | parent customer B | 1 | 1234503 | not inherited |
| 7 | child of B sub 1 | 6 | 1234504 | not inherited |
| 8 | child of BS1 sub 1 | 7 | null | inherited |
| 9 | child of BS1 sub 2 | 7 | null | inherited |
| 10 | child of BS1S2 sub 1 | 9 | null | inherited |

This describes the following hierarchy path:

- parent customer A (has it's own customer_settings)

  - child of A sub 1 (inherits from 'parent customer A')
  - child of A sub 2 (has it's own customer_settings)

    - child of A2 sub 1 (inherits from 'child of A sub 2')
- parent customer B (has it's own customer_settings)

  - child of B sub 1 (has it's own customer_settings)

    - child of B1S1 sub 1 (inherits from 'child of B sub 1')
    - child of B1S1 sub 2 (inherits from 'child of B sub 1')

      - child of BS1S2 sub 1 (inherites from 'child of B sub 1' because 'child of B1S1 sub 2' inherits from 'child of B sub 1')

What I'm trying to do is create a query that will perform a reverse lookup from the current child row in my select to the parent in order to find the first customer_setting value that would be inherited, leading to a result set that looks more like this:

Customers

| id | name | parent_id | customer_settings | inheritance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | parent customer A | 1 | 1234501 | not inherited |
| 3 | child of A sub 1 | 2 | **1234501** | inherited |
| 4 | child of A sub 2 | 2 | 1234502 | not inherited |
| 5 | child of A2 sub 1 | 4 | **1234502** | inherited |
| 6 | parent customer B | 1 | 1234503 | not inherited |
| 7 | child of B sub 1 | 6 | 1234504 | not inherited |
| 8 | child of BS1 sub 1 | 7 | **1234504** | inherited |
| 9 | child of BS1 sub 2 | 7 | **1234504** | inherited |
| 10 | child of BS1S2 sub 1 | 9 | **1234504** | inherited |

There are many different arrangements within these hierarchies, so there are some variations in how many levels inheritance may be coming from. I'd say as a worst case scenario, if something had to be defined, then 10 levels may cover it.

My main issue here is figuring out how to capture those customer_settings from the above objects when that setting is null. Once I have that value for each row, I can then pull other related settings that further define each of those records.

I can recursively look *down* the tables in order to collect the parent-child relationships and paths, but I have no idea how to look up the hierarchy in that same manner. I kept ending up with a single sub-query to look at the parent object (ex sub-query: SELECT customer_setting FROM customers WHERE id = parent_id), but I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to look *up* multiple levels when that first find is null.

I appreciate any help you guys can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to traverse up the table, and then join the CTE to the original table:

```
with recursive cte(old, id, parent, s) as (
   select id, id, parent_id, customer_settings from customers where customer_settings is null
   union all
   select c.old, c1.id, c1.parent_id, c1.customer_settings from cte c join customers c1 on c.parent = c1.id where c.s is null
)
select c.id, c.name, c.parent_id, case when c.customer_settings is null then c1.s else c.customer_settings end, c.inheritance from customers c left join cte c1 on c.id = c1.old and c1.s is not null;
```

Comment: Thank you @Ajax1234 ...that worked beautifully!

Comment: @SiLeNCeD Glad to help!